# No module named 'chardet'

Tags: python, selenium, cx-freeze

I have created an exe using cx_Freeze.
The build was successful.
Then when I was clicking on the exe, I got:-

```
no module named 'queue'
```

So, i researched and added this line:-

```
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Now i'm getting:-

```
no module named 'chardet'.
```

This is the full error i am getting :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "normalapi_2103.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-pac
kages\requests-2.18.4-py3.6.egg\requests\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    import chardet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chardet'
```

And i am not getting what to import...

I have also tried adding

> 'requests' and 'os' packages in setup.py.

But no luck...

Answer (score 0):

This should just be a question of adding `chardet` to `includes` command.

```
build_exe_options = {"includes":["chardet"]}
```

See the [`build_exe`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe) options.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Another fix is to downgrade the version to `chardet==3.0.2`.
I was unable to even do this until I downloaded the subsequent record and metadata files into the chardet folder :

https://rabbit.test.polarvagnen.se/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chardet-3.0.4.dist-info/